# Best way to pass initialized constants

Tags: python, class, inheritance, constants, subclass

I'm going to make an easy example on an application case of mine.
I am developing a gui with tkinter, my work is divided in 3 files:
constants:

```
CostoMedioEnergia = float(0.2) #
IncentivoAutFisico_Prop_Impianti = float(0.2)#
IncentivoAutFisico_DirittoSup = float(0.06)#
IncentivoAutFisico_Finanziatore = float(0.140)#
CostoFotovoltaico = float(1000)
ProduzioneFotovoltaico = float(1300) ##########
IncentivoRitDedicato = float(0.045)#
IncentivoMise = float(0.110)#
IncentivoArera = float(0.009)#
```

another file where I have the prototypes of the classes of users (here an example):

```
class ProprietarioImpianti(Parametri):
    def __init__(self, ConsumiPrevisti, PotenzaContatore, PotenzaFotovoltaicoInstallato, PercEnerAutoconsumo, PercIncentivoAutconsumo, PercEnerCondivisa, PercMise, PercArera, PercIncentivoRitDedicato, IndiceUtente): 
        self.ConsumiPrevisti = ConsumiPrevisti
        self.PotenzaContatore = PotenzaContatore
        self.PotenzaFotovoltaicoInstallato = PotenzaFotovoltaicoInstallato
        self.PercEnerCondivisa = PercEnerCondivisa #Energia in autoconsumo condiviso (percentuale sull'energia totale disponibile alla condivisione)
        self.PercMise = PercMise #Percentuale incentivo Mise attributita all'utente
        self.PercArera = PercArera # Percentuale incentivo Arera attribuita all'utente
        self.PercEnerAutoconsumo = PercEnerAutoconsumo #Percentuale dell'energia prodotta che viene autoconsumata fisicamente
        self.PercIncentivoAutoconsumo = PercIncentivoAutconsumo #Percentuale dell'incentivo autoconsumo attribuito all'utente 
        self.PercIncentivoRitDedicato = PercIncentivoRitDedicato
        self.IndiceUtente = IndiceUtente

    @property
    def CostoMedioBolletta(self): 
        return self.ConsumiPrevisti * self.PotenzaContatore * CostoMedioEnergia
```

As you can see in the last line I'm using "CostoMedioEnergia" which is a constant imported from the previous file. The third and last file is my tkinter gui, you don't necessary need that, where I input some data and instantiate classes accordingly.
My question is: I want to input those constant data from the first file (such as CostoMedioEnergia) form the GUI in tkinter. What would be the best way to update my code so that I can use parameters form input? I thought to create a new class in the second file I mentioned (where all my other classes are) and to use inheritance. But this way I'd add a lot of attributes to my classes when I only need to store that information once and make it accessible to all classes without creating "copies" of the information in my "subclasses".

Comment: define a wrapper class for those variables and bind to ui(it's just like any CRUD application)

Comment: I think that I have no idea of what you are talking about XD sorry. Do you have some reference I can look up?

Comment: this is more about tkinter, not python class. have you ever created a Form with some textboxes, some button to change the value?

Comment: I have created forms within this application. This is a question to understand what's the best way to store constants. I can store some in my controller, but those are linked to my environment. Say I store a constant in my controller, I'd have to pass it to my class initialization to actually use that value. I don't want to do that. I want to store it in some form such that I can use it globally in my classes.

Comment: then just store in global values, just in `constants.py`. you display and update the values to the Form, anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, in which form do I store them (is there a more appropriate data structure?) ? Moreover, say i'm in the tkinter gui file .py, I create some entry widget, can I store the value I input in a varible which is declared on another file?

Comment: you just import the value, and change that value(you may declare as global fisrt)

Comment: So basically you say to try this: declare the constants i need in a separate file. Then create an entry widget in tkinter and update their values with the one I input, then just import the file of the constants in the one of the classes. And the classes should use the const value i used as input. right?

Comment: yes. but note i also said you can wrap them in a class(the class is only data). that will make passing values around more cleaner.

Comment: I was looking up at the concept of wrapper... basically I can store my constants in a function and pass to the function my class which will use those values i priorly saved. It doesn't sound bad but I'd have to remake a lot of my code